# Will this bash loop apt-get install all my anaconda packages?

Tags: bash, anaconda

I don't want to just try it and mess something up.

```
$ dlpackages=$(ls -l anaconda3/bin | awk '{print $9}')
$ for package in $dlpackages; do sudo apt-get install $package; done
```

or as root:     `$ for package in $dlpackages; do apt-get install $package; done`

Comment: Are the things in `anaconda3/bin` package names?  If they are the packages themselves, don't you want `dpkg` not `apt-get`?  I'm not a regular debian/ubuntu user though, so I could be wrong about that.

Comment: Also, you could safely try it if you add `-s` to the `apt-get` to tell it to "simulate" the installation

Comment: **1** [Don't parse `ls`!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) **2** You can `apt-get install package1 package2 package3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a safety check for each package, to see if it can be located.

```
dlpackages=$(ls -l anaconda3/bin | awk '{print $9}')
for package in $dlpackages; do 
    [[ $(apt-cache search $package) ]] && sudo apt-get install $package
done
```

Now for every string, the install will only be executed if the package can be found.

Alternatively use the `-s` option of `install` as *Eric Renouf* suggested.

Comment: Great, thanks.

I ended up going with

    packages=$(ls -l anaconda3/pkgs | awk '{print $9}')
    for package in $packages; do 
        [[ $(apt-cache search $(echo $package | cut -d'-' -f1)) ]] && sudo apt-get install $(echo $package | cut -d'-' -f1)
    done

Worked alright, but obviously not for packages with hyphens in the name...also a bunch of packages weren't found.

Answer (score 1):

In general things in `bin` aren't the same as package names. `conda list` may be closer, but you'll ultimately probably have to figure out the translation of package names manually.